# Spring Cloud; CloudFoundry; spring.jpa properties

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-connectors

I am using spring cloud to bind services to a spring boot application deployed to CloudFoundry. When running locally, I can pass Java options to the application as follows:

```
-Dspring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Now I would like to do the same thing when running the application on CloudFoundry. What's the usual way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to setting a system property or environment variable is to set this as a Spring property in `src/main/resources/application.properties` or `src/main/resources/application.yml`.

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
```

With this approach, the configuration will be applied regardless of now the app is deployed - locally, on CF, or on another platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `env` entry in your manifest.yml file like so:

```
env:
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create-drop
```

See more information here:

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#env-block

Comment: When setting this as an environment variable, you might have to set SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO instead of the dot notation.